# Multiple Client – Server –How every new client to see the current value of variable?

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to make Client-Server application. It’s about library and every new client must see the current stock of the books. I don’t have idea, how the server to send the actual stock when new client starts. In my application the new client always see the initial stock of books. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance. Here is my code:

Server

```
package Server;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

class Readers {
    private ArrayList<PrintWriter> pW;

    public Readers() {
        pW = new ArrayList<PrintWriter>(10);
    }

    public synchronized void addR(PrintWriter p) {
        pW.add(p);
    }

    public synchronized void rmvR(PrintWriter p) {
        pW.remove(p);
    }

    public synchronized void sendR(String s) {
        Iterator<PrintWriter> itr = pW.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            PrintWriter p = (PrintWriter) itr.next();
            p.println(s);
        }
    }

}


class ServeOneReader extends Thread {
    private Socket socket;
    private BufferedReader in;
    private PrintWriter out;
    public static int available1=3;//initial stock of book 1
    public static int available2=3;//initial stock of book 2
    String book1 = "The cat in the had";
    String book2 = "Harry Potter";
    Readers rd;

    public ServeOneReader(Socket s, Readers rd) throws IOException {
        socket = s;
        this.rd = rd;
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        // Enable auto-flush:
        out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                socket.getOutputStream())), true);
        // If any of the above calls throw an
        // exception, the caller is responsible for
        // closing the socket. Otherwise the thread
        // will close it.
        rd.addR(out);
        start(); // Calls run()
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                String str = in.readLine();//client sends suffix "borrowed" or "returned" after book's name
                if (str.equals(book1 + "borrow")) {//check if the book was borrowed
                        available1--;
                        System.out.println("Book " + str + " Stock: " + available1);
                        String answer = book1 + " Stock: " + available1;
                        rd.sendR(answer);
                        out.println(book1);//Server sends back the book's name to the client to identify which stock decreases 
                        out.println(available1);//stock of book 1
                }
                if (str.equals(book2 + "borrow")) {//check if the book was borrowed
                        available2--;
                        System.out.println("Book " + str + " Stock: " + available2);
                        String answer = book2 + " Stock: " + available2;
                        rd.sendR(answer);
                        out.println(book2);
                        out.println(available2);

                }
                if (str.equals(book1 + "returned")) {//check if the book was returned
                        available1++;
                        System.out.println("Book " + str + " Stock: " + available1);
                        String answer = book1 + " Stock: " + available1;
                        rd.sendR(answer);
                        out.println(book1);
                        out.println(available1);
                }
                if (str.equals(book2 + "returned")) {//check if the book was returned
                        available2++;
                        System.out.println("Book " + str + " Stock: " + available2);
                        String answer = book2 + " Stock: " + available2;
                        rd.sendR(answer);
                        out.println(book2);
                        out.println(available2);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        } finally {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}

    enter code here

public class LibrarySrv {
    static final int PORT = 9090;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        System.out.println("Server Started");
        Readers rd = new Readers();
        try {
            while (true) {
                // Blocks until a connection occurs:
                Socket socket = s.accept();
                try {
                    new ServeOneReader(socket, rd);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // If it fails, close the socket,
                    // otherwise the thread will close it:
                    socket.close();
                }
            }
        } finally {
            s.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Client

```
package Server;

import java.net.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

import MyPackige.Books;

public class Reader {
    BufferedReader in;
    PrintWriter out;
    InetAddress addr;
    Socket socket;
    Gui g;

    Reader(JFrame frame) {
        g = new Gui(frame);
    }

    class Gui {

        JPanel panelChB, panelText, panelStock;
        private JLabel title, bookTitle, bookTitle1, stock1, stock2;
        private JButton getBook, returnBook;
        private JCheckBox ch1, ch2;
        boolean haveBook1 = false;
        boolean haveBook2 = false;
        String book1 = "The cat in the had";
        String book2 = "Harry Potter";

        String stockFB=Integer.toString(ServeOneReader.available1);//Stock first book and Stock second book must be equal to the current variable availabel1/2 in Server but it is always 3
        String stockSB =Integer.toString(ServeOneReader.available2); 


        private void updateStockDisplay() { // update the frame after every stock changes
            stock1.setText("Stock: " + stockFB);
            stock2.setText("Stock: " + stockSB);

        }


        Gui(JFrame frame) {
            frame.setSize(400, 150);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setTitle("Books");
            frame.setResizable(false);
            frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            frame.setVisible(true);


            panelChB = new JPanel();
            panelChB.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panelChB, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

            ch1 = new JCheckBox();
            ch2 = new JCheckBox();
            getBook = new JButton("Borrow");
            getBook.addActionListener(new SrvL());
            (new Rcv()).start();
            returnBook = new JButton("Return");
            returnBook.addActionListener(new SrvL1());

            panelChB.add(ch1);
            panelChB.add(ch2);
            panelChB.add(getBook);
            panelChB.add(returnBook);

            panelText = new JPanel();
            panelText.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panelText, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
            bookTitle = new JLabel("The cat in the had");
            bookTitle1 = new JLabel("Harry Potter");
            panelText.add(bookTitle);
            panelText.add(bookTitle1);

            panelStock = new JPanel();
            panelStock.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panelStock, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
            stock1 = new JLabel();
            stock2 = new JLabel();
            updateStockDisplay();
            panelStock.add(stock1);
            panelStock.add(stock2);

            frame.add(panelChB, BorderLayout.WEST);
            frame.add(panelText, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            frame.add(panelStock, BorderLayout.EAST);




        }



        class SrvL implements ActionListener {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (ch1.isSelected() || ch2.isSelected()) { //check if a book is selected
                    if (ch1.isSelected() && haveBook1==false) {// check if book 1 is selected
                        String infoMessage = "Book \"" + book1 + "\" borrowed";
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, infoMessage,
                                "Message: ", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                        out.println(book1 + "borrow");//send to the server suffix "borrow" after book's name to indicate the stock has to be decrease
                        haveBook1 = true;//the client can't borrow the same book anymore 

                    }
                    if (ch2.isSelected()  && haveBook2==false) {
                        String infoMessage = "Book \"" + book2 + " \" borrowed";
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, infoMessage,
                                "Message: ", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                        out.println(book2 + "borrow");
                        haveBook2 = true;
                    }
                } else {
                    String infoMessage = "No book selected";
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, infoMessage,
                            "Message: ", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                }
            }

        }

        class SrvL1 implements ActionListener {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (ch1.isSelected() || ch2.isSelected()) {
                    if (ch1.isSelected() && haveBook1==true) {
                        String infoMessage = "Book \"" + book1
                                + " \"  returned";
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, infoMessage,
                                "Message: ", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                        out.println(book1 + "returned");
                        haveBook1 = false;

                    }
                    if (ch2.isSelected() && haveBook2==true) {

                        String infoMessage = "Book \"" + book2
                                + " \"  returned";
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, infoMessage,
                                "Message: ", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                        out.println(book2 + "returned");
                        haveBook2 = false;
                    }
                } else {
                    String infoMessage = "No book selected";
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, infoMessage,
                            "Message: ", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                }

            }

        }

        //Receive data from the server 

        class Rcv extends Thread {
            public void run() {
                for (;;) {
                    try {
                        sleep(400);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                    try {
                        String infoMessage = in.readLine();
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, infoMessage,
                                "Message: ", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                        String stock=in.readLine();//Server sends book's name and current stock
                        if(stock.contains(book1)){//check which book it comes
                            stockFB = in.readLine();//Server sends only current stock
                            updateStockDisplay();
                        }
                        if(stock.contains(book2)){
                            stockSB = in.readLine();
                            updateStockDisplay();
                        }

                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(" closing reading thread...");
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (Exception expt) {
                    System.out.println(expt);
                }
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }


    }



    public void init() throws IOException {
        try {
            String server = "192.0.0.0";
            InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(server);
            System.out.println("addr = " + addr);
            socket = new Socket(addr, LibrarySrv.PORT);
            System.out.println("socket = " + socket);
            // BufferedReader sin = new BufferedReader(
            // new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    socket.getInputStream()));
            // Output is automatically flushed
            // by PrintWriter:
            out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                    socket.getOutputStream())), true);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("exception: " + e);
            System.out.println("closing...");
            socket.close();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        Reader rd = new Reader(frame);
        rd.init();

    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't really the cleanest way you could do this. Anyways, try declaring your available counts as `volatile`; e.g. `public static volatile int available1=3`. Perhaps the compiler optimized them into locals, or they are cached. You could also use proper synchronization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use operation code that needs to be sent between client and server before passing any data back & forth.

For e.g.:

- CLIENT_ADDED
- CLIENT_REMOVED
- SERVER_STARTED
- SERVER_STOPPED
- BOOK_BORROWED
- BOOK_RETURNED

etc...

**Set a communication protocol between client and server.**

Steps to be followed to check the stock data for newly added client:

- Whenever a new client is added just send a operation code `CLIENT_ADDED` to the server.
- Server will send back the stock information back to client
- Client will receive the stock data and will update its UI.

Same steps are followed for each type of operation code.

Here is a modification in your code as per your requirement:

**ServerOneReader:**

```
public void run() {
    try {
        while (true) {
            String str = in.readLine();// client sends suffix "borrowed" or "returned" after
                                       // book's name
            if(str.equals("client_added")){
                String answer1 = book1 + " Stock: " + available1;
                rd.sendR(answer);
                String answer2 = book2 + " Stock: " + available2;
                rd.sendR(answer2);
            }
            if (str.equals(book1 + "borrow")) {// check if the book was borrowed
                available1--;
            ...
```

Answer (score 0):

When you client starts up send a message to server to get the current info on Book Stock.

In the server you are already listening to different type of messages, let it handle one more message - GetStockInfo. You can then send the names of the books that are stored on the server to the client.

This should solve your issue.